# Calculating future date in php using time()

Tags: php, datetime, date, time

I'm trying to show the time 10 days from now.

```
$now = time();

$est = ($now - (60 * 60 * 4)); // subtract 4 hours

$later = ($est + (60*60*24*10));

$show_now = date('M m, Y h:i:s A', $est); // correct

$show_later = date('M m, Y h:i:s A', $later); // showing same as above...WHY!?

echo "now: ".$show_now."<br />later: ".$show_later;
```

Both echo the same time. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$show_now = date('M m, Y h:i:s A', $est); // correct
$show_later = date('M m, Y h:i:s A', $later); // showing same as above...WHY!?
```

should be

```
$show_now = date('M d, Y h:i:s A', $est); // correct
$show_later = date('M d, Y h:i:s A', $later); // NOT showing same as above
```

else you don't show the **day**, resulting in identical output before the 20th of each month